# ERROR MESSAGE: untrusted packages and libdrm-nouveau1a libdrm-radeon1

Tags: updates, update-manager, software-updater

Ubuntu finds update but when I click on install update, it gives an error. I released that there are some people out there who's getting that message too, but mine is different and non of the solutions worked for me.

update-manager
Requires installation of untrusted packages
This requires installing packages from unauthenticated sources.
libdrm-nouveau1a libdrm-radeon1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,  i found out that the problem is caused by Intel Linux Graphics Installer. So I followed the instructions in the link and the problem has disappered. http://theclonker.de/?p=89